# Rails Link Generation/Caching Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, spree

I am using [Spree Commerce](https://spreecommerce.com/) deployed through Cloud 66 and running on Digital Ocean servers. Nginx is my web server.

If someone visits my site via one of the server's IP addresses rather than the domain name it seems like the cached links become "infected" with the ip address. Going forward, the cached links use the IP address as the base URL rather than the site's FQDN.

For example, let's say my site's FQDN is "store.mystore.com" and its ip address is 45.5.5.235. Someone (or some bot) visits the products index via the ip address rather than the FQDN. They visit "https://45.5.5.555/products". Going forward, the cached links that used to show "https://store.mystore.com/products/product-1" now show up as "https://45.5.5.235/products/product-1".

I'm using site-wide SSL that is tied to my FQDN, so a big nasty warning shows up in the user's browsers warning them that the site they're about to click on isn't the one they think it is. Not good for ecommerce, obviously.

If I manually clear the cache then the problem is corrected until another bot/crawler visits the site via ip address.

I'm using memcached and Dalli, if that makes any difference. I am setting the site URL in Spree's admin panel.

Is there anything I can do to ensure that Rails-generated links *always* use the FQDN rather than the server's IP address?

**EDIT**

Eirikir's answer is pretty much correct, however I have a HAProxy load balancer switching between two different servers. I put two server blocks at the end of my nginx config, one listening on port 80 for http, and one listening on 443 for https.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name haproxy_ip rails_server_ip;
        return 301 $scheme://store.mystore.com$request_uri;
}

    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name haproxy_ip rails_server_ip;
        return 301 $scheme://store.mystore.com$request_uri;
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it seems to work so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link caching issue is contingent on the fact that your site is accessible via multiple domains (including the IP). This is terrible for SEO, since search engines may consider your canonical domain as duplicates of the alternate domains.

You don't mention if you're using Apache, Nginx, or another server, but that would be the best place for a 301 redirect to your canonical production domain. Some DNS services also encapsulate this feature as a certain DNS record type. You would need to find how to do this in your server/DNS configuration.

If its not possible for you to perform the redirect on the DNS or server level, you can implement the redirect in a before_filter in application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :redirect_to_canonical_host if Rails.env.production?

private
CANONICAL_HOST = "store.mystore.com"
def redirect_to_canonical_host
  unless request.host == CANONICAL_HOST
    redirect_to "https://#{CANONICAL_HOST}#{request.fullpath unless request.fullpath == '/'}", status: :moved_permanently
  end
end
```

Again, this isn't optimal since an Apache or Nginx redirect would be much faster, and I'm worried server admins will downvote me for this, but there are cases where it can't be avoided.

ETA: I'm no Nginx expert by any means, but I don't believe wildcards are available for `server_name`, so you'd have to write a `server` block with a redirect for each possible IP or alternative hostname, e.g.:

```
server {
        server_name 45.5.5.555;
        return 301 $scheme://store.mystore.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the SEO implications. You're right, I didn't mention what server I am using (nginx). I've updated the question to include this information.

Comment: Also, this answer gives me the Google keyword ammo I need to get started looking for a solution: canonical url, 301, nginx, etc.

Comment: @michaelmichael Edited with an untested Nginx solution. Let me know if you find anything better, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Your answer was right, and got me looking in the right direction. Edited my question to give answers specific to Cloud66 and my particular setup in case it helps someone else with the same issue.